# How would working directory look like in tree diagram?

Tags: git, tree, rebase, working-directory

I get the last commit which exists in the master branch like this:

```
$ git pull origin master
```

Then I make some changes in it. Noted that, in the same time *(whenever I was working on the project)*, my co-worker has pushed some new commits to the master branch.

So I have to rebase my changes first and then push it to the master branch. Here is my commands:

```
git pull origin master --rebase
git push origin master
```

Now I want to know:

1. How does the whole process look like in git tree diagram?
2. Also, can I write `git pull origin master --rebase` the other way? I mean is `--rebase` a shorten for `$ git checkout workingDirecotry` and `$ git rebase master` ?

Comment: Your second pull isn't necessary. The first pull with rebase simply reapply your commits on top of the origin/master from the remote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your first pull, the history is like:
[image]

After you make some changes, the local branch moves on:
[image]

Meanwhile, the remote repo has been updated by your co-worker:
[image]

Then you run `git pull origin master --rebase`, which is equivalent to `git fetch origin master && git rebase origin/master`.

As a result of `git fetch origin master`:
[image]

And then `git rebase origin/master`. `D` and `E` are transplanted from the old base `C` onto the new base `N`. `master` also moves from the old head `E` to the new head `E'`.
[image]

Comment: I guess the word in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC7QR.png) should be `origin/master`, not `master`

Comment: @stack It's in the remote repo, so it should be `master`. `origin/master` is a tracking branch in the local repo.

Comment: No. The 3rd image describes the remote repo and the others describe the local repo. There is `origin/master` in the local repo because it's created and updated during the last communication between the local and the remote. There may be an `origin/master` in the remote repo, but it's irrelevant in this case.

Comment: I see nowm upvote. Can you please tell me when exactly `rebase` is dangerous? I saw a tutorial which said never used `rebase`. why?

Comment: @stack Rebase can be dangerous when it changes the fixed part of the history of a published branch. As you see, when a rebase is done, new commits are created, like `D` and `D'`, `E` and `E'`, and the branch head is changed as `master` moves from `E` to `E'`. In this case the published branch is `master` in the remote repo, and the fixed part is `A-B-C-M-N`. As long as this part is and will be included in the history of `master` of the remote repo, you can do anything to manipulate the history. You can change the fixed part locally, but not okay to push it to update `master` in the remote.